# How can I redefine \autoref?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, labels

I am redefining a few things to support unique references in multilingual documents such that **labels must only be unique within a given locale from the users perspective** (obviously they must always be unique):

```
\label
\ref
\autoref
\nameref
```

Because I am using `hyperref`, which defines them at `\AtBeginDocument`, I need to grab their definitions at that point.

---

## Update 2016.06.15

I realized that `\addlabelsuffix` may only be called within the BODY. Because I call `\setlocale` sometimes before `\begin{document}`, I needed to remove `\addlabelsuffix` from that macro. It will instead be called in a separate `\inputlanguagefile` macro not shown here. *If you try using `\addlabelsuffix` before `\begin{document}`, then you might run into issues with the macro being protected--probably due to `\hyperref`.*

---

## Problems

1. I must be tired because my example looks good to me, but the output is not as expected. The Norwegian section is not showing up as a section.
2. I also noticed that `\autoref` is protected in my real document, hence having an expansion problem (`##1-#1`). I am not sure what is protecting it. Any ideas what packages influence this? In the example code, it does not appear to be protected (tested with `\show\autoref`).

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring}

\AtBeginDocument{% Must come after hyperref (because hyperref modifies \label and \ref system)
  \let\oldlabel\label% Copy original
  \let\oldref\ref% Copy original
  \let\oldautoref\autoref% Copy original
}

\newcommand{\addlabelsuffix}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{##1-#1}}% Update % This works
  \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\oldref{##1-#1}}% Update % This works
  \renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{\oldautoref{##1-#1}}% Update
  %\show\autoref
}

\newcommand{\locale}{en-US}% Set default locale

\DeclareRobustCommand{\setlocale}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\locale}{#1}
  \addlabelsuffix{#1}% keep labels unique
  \IfEq{#1}{en-US}{%
    \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
  }
  \IfEq{#1}{de-AT}{%
    \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Kapitel}
  }
  \IfEq{#1}{nn-NO}{%
    \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Kapittel}
  }
}%

\begin{document}

\setlocale{en-US}% set locale
\section{US English}
\label{test}
First sentence \autoref{test}.

\setlocale{de-AT}% set locale
\section{Austrian German}
\label{test}
First sentence \autoref{test}.

\setlocale{nn-NO}% set locale
\section{Norwegian}
\label{test}
First sentence \autoref{test}.

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `\IfEq{foo}{foobar}{true}{false}` has a `true`/`false` argument pair at the end -- this was missing in all tests within the definition of `\setlocale`, such that `\section` etc. was gobbled up, leading to being omitted here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\AtBeginDocument{% Must come after hyperref (because hyperref modifies \label and \ref system)
  \let\oldlabel\label% Copy original
  \let\oldref\ref% Copy original
  \let\oldautoref\autoref% Copy original
}

\newcommand{\addlabelsuffix}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{##1-#1}}% Update % This works
  \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\oldref{##1-#1}}% Update % This works
  \renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{\oldautoref{##1-#1}}% Update
  %\show\autoref
}

\newcommand{\locale}{en-US}% Set default locale

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\setlocale}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\locale}{#1}%
    \addlabelsuffix{#1}% keep labels unique
    \IfEq{#1}{en-US}{%
      \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
    }{}%
    \IfEq{#1}{de-AT}{%
      \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Kapitel}
    }{}%
    \IfEq{#1}{nn-NO}{%
      \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Kapittel}
    }{}%
}%
}

\begin{document}

\setlocale{en-US}% set locale
\section{US English}
\label{test}
First sentence \autoref{test}.

\setlocale{de-AT}% set locale
\section{Austrian German}
\label{test}
First sentence \autoref{test}.

\setlocale{nn-NO}% set locale
\section{Norwegian}
\label{test}
First sentence \autoref{test}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I feel like such an idiot for missing those extra braces `{}`

Comment: @macmadness86: Such things can happen, never mind.

Answer (score 5):

You're forgetting an argument to `\IfEq`:

```
\IfEq{<string-a>}{<string-b>}{<true>}{<false>}
```

and the false branch is missing. Besides, `\ref` and `\autoref` are “robusted” commands, so it's better to use `\LetLtxMacro` for saving copies of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{% Must come after hyperref (because hyperref modifies \label and \ref system)
  \let\oldlabel\label% Copy original
  \LetLtxMacro\oldref\ref% Copy original
  \LetLtxMacro\oldautoref\autoref% Copy original
}

\newcommand{\addlabelsuffix}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{##1-#1}}% Update % This works
  \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\oldref{##1-#1}}% Update % This works
  \renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{\oldautoref{##1-#1}}% Update
}

\newcommand{\locale}{en-US}% Set default locale

\DeclareRobustCommand{\setlocale}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\locale}{#1}%
  \addlabelsuffix{#1}% keep labels unique
  \IfEq{#1}{en-US}{%
    \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}%
  }{}%
  \IfEq{#1}{de-AT}{%
    \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Kapitel}%
  }{}%
  \IfEq{#1}{nn-NO}{%
    \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Kapittel}%
  }{}%
}

\begin{document}

\setlocale{en-US}% set locale
\section{US English}
\label{test}
First sentence \autoref{test}.

\setlocale{de-AT}% set locale
\section{Austrian German}
\label{test}
First sentence \autoref{test}.

\setlocale{nn-NO}% set locale

\section{Norwegian}
\label{test}
First sentence \autoref{test}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I gave it to Christian only because he was faster. Your answers are both useful (your comment about the robust commands and his about the gobbling up of `\section` and his screenshot is prettier :-p)